# Understanding if statements

Tags: java

I have done thorough research on If statements in java, but I can't for the life of me understand them.

I get that you're supposed to put in a sort of true or false statement and if it meets the requirements of the if Statement then it does something. I however do not fully understand how to write them. If someone can possibly write an example and explain it that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if (you show us some code) { System.out.println("We can help you with that"); } else { No help }`

Comment: Seriously, "I've done extensive research" should start with "I read a Java tutorial, in the suggested order". And seriously, that should sort it out. How should we be explaining this better to you than the thousands of good introductions to Java that exist? Vote to close as too broad.

Comment: "*I have done thorough research on If statements in java...If someone can possibly write an example and explain it*" it is hard to believe that you didn't find any example with explanation. Have you seen official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html? Can you point out specific part which is unclear?

Comment: The only reason, if any, to keep this question, is because someone just wrote a really good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If statements are sometimes hard to understand if they aren't explained well. In hopes to help I'll show you some examples and explain how they work.

First you need to understand that an `if` statement is not as simple as `True` or `False`. It works more as if the given situation in code meets the requirements you set for it between the parenthesis it will run the code inside the brackets of the `if` statement.

Example 1:

```
int x = 5;

if(x == 5)
{

     System.out.println(" X is equal to 5");

}
```

Whats happening hear is you are initializing the `int x` to be `5` and then the if statements runs to see if `x` is equal to `5`. Since it is the code inside the `if` statement is run and it prints out the sentence. `X is equal to 5`.

If the the `int x` was equal to anything but five in this situation the `if` statement would not run the code inside because it failed to meet the requirements. Similarly you can use different operators such as; does not equal(`!=`), greater than or less than(`<`, `>`), and greater to or equal to and less than or equal to(`<=`, `>=`).

If you want to get more complex you can go as far as to add and or or operators in(`||`, or `&&`). This allows you to set multiple requirements in one `if` statement.

Example 2:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 2;

if(x == 5 || y == 5)
{

     System.out.println("I <3 if statements");

}
```

What is happening in this example is the `if` statement is checking to see if either `y` or `x` is equal to `5`. Since one of them is (x) it runs the code inside the `if` statement printing out the sentence. `I <3 if statements`.

With the use of the or operate only if neither of the requirements are met will it not operate the code inside. Having both the requirements be met is fine because at least one of them are.

Also when using `||` you are not limited to only 2 requirements you can go on to make as many as you desire.

Example 3:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 2;

if(x == 5 && y == 2)
{

    System.out.println("Coding is fun");

}
```

With the and operator, the `if` statement checks to see if both the requirements are met. In this example since `x` is equal to `5` and `y` is equal to `2` the code in the `if` statement will run printing the text. `Coding is fun`.

If you look to get more in depth you can also use `else if` and `else` statements. How the work is simply if the requirements of the previous `if` statements were not met than it will either run the code if it is an `else` statement or check to see if the next set of requirements are met in the `else if` statement.

Example 4:

```
int x = 5;

if(x == 1)
{

    System.out.println("X is 1");

}

else if(x == 3)
{

    System.out.println("X is 3");

}

else
{

    System.out.println("X is unknown");

}
```

What is happening is that the original if statement is checking to see if `x` is equal to `1`. Since it is not the code inside the `if` statement is not run and it moves on to the else if statement. The `else if` statement is checking to see if `x` is equal to `3`. Once again since it is not it skips over the code inside the `else if` statement and moves the the `else` statement. With the `else` statement since there is no requirements it runs the code inside no matter what and finally prints out the sentence. `X is unknown`.

In the event that the requirements in one of the previous statements(`if`, or `else if`) is met it will run the code inside the given one and terminate there. In other words it won't run the else regardless, only if everything else fails.

I hope I was able to help with your problem. Enjoy your coding experiences! :)

Comment: Re "With the and operator, the if statement checks to see if both the requirements are met." No, it doesn't. It checks whether the 1st is met & *only if it is* does it check whether the 2nd is met. (Similarly for "the if statement is checking to see if either y or x is equal to 5.") The problem in explaining `&&` & `||` in an explanation of `if` is that like it they rely on the notion of conditional evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a value x that you want to check if it's bigger or smaller than five for example you can do this :

```
int x ;
if(x>5) { // you're checking if x is bigger than 5 

    // If true print it's bigger...
    System.out.print("It's bigger than five");

}else{ // anything else (if not bigger) print it's not bigger...

    System.out.print("It's not bigger than five");
}
```

So if x was 6 for example output would be 
It's bigger than five

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "thorough research on If statements", but the principle is simple.

There's always some kind of expression that might turn out to be true or false.  It's written in parentheses.  Then there's a bunch of statements that are usually (but not always) written between curly braces.  Some naughty developers sometimes omit the braces, if there's only one statement, but it's arguably best not to do this.

The computer starts by working out whether the expression in parentheses is true or false.  If it's true, the statements in the braces are run.  If it's false, the statements in the braces are ignored.

For example,

```
if (today.equals("Friday")) {
   developers.goHome("early");
   managers.stay("late");
}
```

Here, if `today.equals("Friday")` turns out to be true, the two statements inside the braces are run.  Otherwise, they are not.